# multithreaded programming c. Mutexes not working

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a multithreaded c program written with pthreads.  I want to know if what I am doing is right.  Currently the program seems to run when there are no optimizations.  But when I use optimizations, it fails. I am trying to figure out why.

I want to know if the basic multi threading synchronization that I am using is correct.  Here is a short version which contains only the relevant parts.  Please let me know if this is the correct way to multithread.

The way it works:
Each worker has a number of jobs to do.  The worker threads are initiated first.  Then they wait until a job has been assigned to them by the main thread.  They complete the job, intimate the main thread and go back to waiting again.

The main thread assigns a job to N workers and signals them to start.  Then it waits for their completion and resumes normal work.

Each worker thread has a context variable named workerCtx.  This stores all the relevant info needed by the worker and also the mutexs and the cond variables.

The main thread has a mutex and a cond variable too.

Also the parent has variable called the threadCompletionCount.  Initially this variable is 0 before assigning the work.  Once each worker thread is done, it will increment this variable by one under the protection of a mutex and signal the parent thread.  The parent thread will know that all the workers have completed when this variable is equal to the number of workers.

Here is a short version of the workerCtx

```
typedef enum {INITIALIZE = 0 , WAIT = 1, WORK1 = 2, WORK2 =3, DIE = 4} worktype_t;

typedef struct workerCtx_t
{
    int id;

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;

    pthread_mutex_t * parentMutex;
    pthread_cond_t * parentCond;
    int * parentThreadCompletionCount;

    worktype_t workType;

    //Other application specific variables follow.
}workerCtx_t;
```

Here mutex and cond refer to the local mutex and cond variables specific to this thread.  The parentMutex and parentCond are varibles referring to the parent's varibles.  All the threads point to the same parentMutex and parentCond.

Here is how the main thread works:

```
void waitForWorkerCompletion()
{
    int status;

    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (threadCompletionCount < NUM_WORKERS) 
    {
        status = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        threadCompletionCount = 0;
    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void assignWorkToWorker(worktype_t workType)
{
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(workerCtxs[i]->mutex) );
            workerCtxs[i]->workType = workType;
            pthread_cond_signal(&(workerCtxs[i]->cond) );
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(workerCtxs[i]->mutex));      
    }
    waitForWorkerCompletion();
}

void setup
{
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_WORKERS; i++)
    {       
        workerCtxs[i]->id = i;
        workerCtxs[i]->workType = WAIT;

        assert( pthread_mutex_init(&(workerCtxs[i]->mutex), NULL) == 0) ;
        assert( pthread_cond_init(&(workerCtxs[i]->cond), NULL) == 0);

        workerCtxs[i]->parentMutex = &mutex;
        workerCtxs[i]->parentCond = &cond;
        workerCtxs[i]->parentThreadCompletionCount = &threadCompletionCount;

        pthread_create (&(workers[i]), NULL, workerMain, (workerCtxs[i]) );

    }
}

int main()
{
    setup()

    For each work (workType_t workType) that comes up
        assignWorkToWorker(workType);
}
```

Here is what each worker does:

```
void signalCompletion(workerCtx_t * ctx)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->mutex);
        ctx->workType = WAIT;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx->mutex);

    int rc = pthread_mutex_lock(ctx->parentMutex);
        *(ctx->parentThreadCompletionCount) = *(ctx->parentThreadCompletionCount) + 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(ctx->parentCond);
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(ctx->parentMutex);
}

void * workerMain(void * arg)
{
    workerCtx_t * ctx = (workerCtx_t *) arg;

    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->mutex);
        while(ctx->workType == WAIT);
        {
            int status = pthread_cond_wait(&ctx->cond, &ctx->mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx->mutex);

        if(ctx->workType == INITIALIZE)
        {
            init(ctx);
            signalCompletion(ctx);
        }
        else if(ctx->workType == WORK1)
        {
            doWork1(ctx);
            signalCompletion(ctx);
        }
        else if(ctx->workType == WORK2)
        {
            doWork2(ctx);
            signalCompletion(ctx);
        }
        else if(ctx->workType == DIE)
        {
            signalCompletion(ctx);
            break;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I hope that I have made this easy enough to understand and taken out all application oriented details out from the code posted.  This code just handles the multithreading part.  Now the program hangs.  When I use gdb, it tells me that it is waiting in *waitForWorkerCompletion()* method.

Is this multithreading model correct??

Comment: I don't see any mention of [`pthread_mutex_init`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init). Are you sure you've initialized your mutex correctly?

Comment: I ve added that code too.  In case it helps.  Its all done in the setup method.

Comment: last time I checked, they were still working...

Comment: @Ulterior Are you saying that this model works fine and there are no bugs in it?

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman no no, I meant in general ;)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code here (other than the missing declarations and inits for the globals `mutex` and `cond`), though since you have a fixed number of workers it might be more efficient to use `pthread_barrier` instead

Comment: I assume the line `while(ctx->workType == WAIT);` is a cut&paste error?  Because that semicolon changes everything.

Comment: The second [c] bug today due to a stray semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the heck, I will make this an answer.

The following line looks very suspicious:

```
while(ctx->workType == WAIT);
```

I do not think you want the semi-colon there.  With it, you are subject to a variety of strange race conditions...  Which could explain why the behavior differs between non-optimized and optimized builds.

Otherwise, I see nothing wrong with this code.  It is a bit of a strange way to use a worker pool, but it looks to me like it should work.

Comment: I just found the same thing myself!! it was the semi colon! Wonder how that crept into the code! So much for all the effort in posting this code.

Comment: The usual approach is to have one or more queues of work with one or more workers pulling tasks off of each queue.  In this case, it looks like you want all of the workers to do the same thing...  But waiting on the count still feels fragile to me.  I might just wait for each worker to set its state back to "WAIT", ditching the global count.

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman: Yeah, the better way is to put the work selection logic in the thread. By telling a specific thread to do a specific job, you make it impossible to work on that job until that specific thread runs, which kills performance. Just have a queue of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following global declarations somewhere, I don't see anything wrong:

```
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int threadCompletionCount = 0;
workerCtx_t workerCtxs[NUM_WORKERS];
```

Comment: Its for the global variables (shared by all threads) mutex and coord